# How to Get Array Value Inside Array Value

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, foreach, while-loop

searching on Google but still can't get any result that solving  my array problem. I think I just don't know how to search it properly.

I build an array inside array to my website with coma (,) and * :

```
$array ='text1a*text1b,text2a*text2b,.. etc.. ';
```

etc.. but max 20x (,) coma

I explode (, ) coma to convert to array :

```
[0] => text1a*text1b
[1] => text2a*text2b
```

and then explode * to convert result array above. my question, how to get all value from that array and store to form html like this :

```
<input type="text" name="text1a" value="text1a">

<input type="text" name="text1b" value="text1b">

<input type="text" name="text2a" value="text2a">

<input type="text" name="text2b" value="text2b">
```

etc.. max 20x..

Thx before..

Answer (score 1):

```
$array ='text1a*text1b,text2a*text2b';
$C_arr = explode(',',$array);
$count = count($C_arr);
if($count>0){
    foreach($C_arr as $C_ar){
        $S_arr = explode('*',$C_ar);
        foreach($S_arr as $S_ar){
            echo $S_ar;
            echo '<input type="text" name="'.$S_ar.'" value="'.$S_ar.'"><br>';
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope huhuju :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$texts='text1a*text1b,text2a*text2b';

$exploded_comma = explode(",",$texts);

if(count($exploded_comma) > 0 && count($exploded_comma) <= 20) {

    foreach($exploded_comma as $text) {

        $exploded_asterisk = explode("*",$text);

        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$exploded_asterisk[0].'" value="'.$exploded_asterisk[1].'">';

    }


}
```

Comment: it will limit depend of the text provided by the comma

Comment: but it's not from me but from fisitor. imagine if someone input 10000 array? then my server quickly down. that why I ask about adding limit function. BTW thx

Answer (score 0):

You might also split on a comma and asterix using [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and then use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to take up to 40 items as they are pairs of 2.

```
$s = "text1a*text1b,text2a*text2b";
$items = array_slice(preg_split("/[,*]/", $s), 0, 40);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="' . $item . '" value="' . $item . '">' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
<input type="text" name="text1a" value="text1a">
<input type="text" name="text1b" value="text1b">
<input type="text" name="text2a" value="text2a">
<input type="text" name="text2b" value="text2b">
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/PDZTu)